# Return value of series where position is determined by minimum value of an array

Tags: excel

Using the example data table below as a guide

Image of table

[image: image of table]

I need to return the value in the first column that corresponds to the minimum value in the column where the that column header is equal to a referenced value.  I have been trying to use the following array equation, but I only get the minimum value and can't figure out how to reference the other column.

`{=MIN(IF((B1:D1=*the reference value in this case "xy"*),B2:D8))}`

The result I am looking for is "T3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(-98^99,INDEX(B2:D8,0,MATCH(G2,B1:D1,0))),A2:A8)`

where it is assumed that no value within the range `B2:D8` is smaller than -98^99.

Regards

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much for the help!